# Is it possible to change the name of the AWSELB cookie set by AWS ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have two ELBs that handle requests from the same domain and both of them use cookies named AWSELB and I want to know whether it is possible to change one of them to a different value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Amazon support, it is not possible to change the name of the AWSELB cookie.